# Subquery GROUP BY operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of Cards and Posts, and each Card and Post entry has at least 2 tags. The current query uses `card_to_tags_link` and `post_to_tags_link` tables to get all posts grouped by a specific card.

```sql
SELECT 
  card,
  count(post.id) AS count_1, 
  max(post.date) AS max_1

FROM 
  card 
  JOIN card_to_tags_link ON card.id = card_to_tags_link.card_id 
  JOIN post_to_tags_link ON post_to_tags_link.post_tags @>card_to_tags_link.card_tags 
  JOIN post ON post_to_tags_link.post_id = post.id 

GROUP BY 
  card.id
```

Now, because each post has a `post_owner` column, I want to aggregate all posts by `author_url` and order by a number of posts:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY(post.author_url
from post
group_by post.author_url
order by count(post.id)
limit by 10)
```

It is a simple query when executed on its own, but I want to add it as a subquery to the existing one:

```sql
SELECT 
  card,
  count(post.id) AS count_1, 
  max(post.date) AS max_1,
  **ADD SUBQUERY HERE**

FROM 
  card 
  JOIN card_to_tags_link ON card.id = card_to_tags_link.card_id 
  JOIN post_to_tags_link ON post_to_tags_link.post_tags @>card_to_tags_link.card_tags 
  JOIN post ON post_to_tags_link.post_id = post.id 

GROUP BY 
  card.id
```

Is it possible to have the author query as a subquery and return the result as an array?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `ARRAY_AGG()`?

```
SELECT card,
       count(post.id) AS count_1, 
        max(post.date) AS max_1,
       ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT post.author_url)
```